# Django Insert to MSSQL database is not working

Tags: sql-server, django, insert

first of all i am new to django , and it's my first project using django . So the project basically does inserting of dat from UI to datbase table . but whatever i try am not getting any error but the value is not getting inserted .

so the below is my code :
**Views.py**

```
def pg3(request):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=ABC\Aurora;'
                          'Database=hi;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    if request.method == 'POST' :
        print('hi')
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        #myfilename=request.post.get('myfile')
        PatchVersion=request.POST.get('PatchVersion')
        cursor5 = conn.cursor()
        cursor5.execute(
            "insert into PatchInstallers values('" + PatchVersion + "')")
        cursor5.commit()

        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'tech/pg3.html', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })
    context = {
        'result': result,

        'result4': result4,


    }

    return render(request, 'tech/pg3.html', context)
```

here i wanted to store PatchVersion inside dbtable ,

so here is my html / pg3.html

```
<label for="patchversion">PatchInstaller Version:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="PatchVersion">
```

and here is my table headers :[![table Headers][1]][1]

i made required changes in settings.py too . but in vain
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUpcb.png

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the Django ORM?

Comment: no particular reason @IainShelvington , was that the reason